# How do I get the Catwoman trophy in the room with Nora and Mr Freeze?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I'm trying to get the trophy for Catwoman that is where Mr Freeze and Nora are. I did the side mission for those two but it still won't let me into the building to get the trophy for the cat.

Answer (score 6):

If I remember correctly you will need to get back into the building as Batman (I think you use a freeze grenade near the river in order to get in from underneath rather than the main door) and then you have to hack the door lock/security panel. Once you do this Catwoman will be able to get in and pick up the trophy.

I'm trying to find a guide/source for this, I will update when I do.

**Edit:** not the best source, but [this question](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/981374-batman-arkham-city/answers?qid=298221) corroborates what I said.

By the way, it appears some players have experienced a [bug](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=339490) where they would not be able to get into the room, even after unlocking it with Batman. For some, turning the game off and on again fixed the issue.